# how to detect .flv movie file URL?

Tags: php, javascript, flv

when theres a flash video, how can i detect the current flv URL ? viewing the source doesn't reveal it. However, I wonder if theres any approach to figuring out the .flv URL (Where it's hosted at the moment it's being streamed).

I see that there are firefox add on's that does this. I wonder how these work, and whether it can be implemented purely in php and javascript.

Comment: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618923/how-to-detect-flv-download-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLV videos are basically flat files with a standard header.  The first three bytes are `F`, `L`, and (get this) `V`.  So, if you can inspect the first three bytes of a binary in JavaScript, then you can check the file header.

*(Technically, the web server could give the browser any kind of file extension or MIME type.  But the Flash players don't really care--they try to play a file no matter what the extension or header is.)*